# Does the Schengen Visa (short stay) application for France really require a fully prepaid accommodation? Too much inconsistent information online

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

Some travel agencies in the UK, for instance [this](http://www.anyvisa.co.uk/visa-application-requirements/pakistan-national-france-tourist-visa) one specify below.

> Proof of accommodation **fully paid**, if possible, in the name of
>   applicant. Should come directly from the hotel Return ticket fully
>   paid, in the name of applicant

Another [one](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/france-visa/uk/) says this below.

> Proof of accommodation in France: **Evidence of a hotel booking** in
>   France or a rental agreement,

This is inconsistent with what I have researched otherwise on the internet. I am a Pakistani citizen living and working in the UK and I wish to know if a Booking.com **confirmed booking** will suffice?

Some hotels have no way of prepaying and only accept payment at check-in/check-out so I am not sure what to do here. Confirming bookings do validate the debit card.

Comment: Always remember travel agencies are NOT the embassy.

Comment: Apparently that agency is verified by TLS

Comment: It doesn’t matter. Same way VFS is certified by UK Immigrarion but routinely give bad information.

Comment: So what really is the correct information ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will vary depending on the agency or information source you look into. It is best to just rely on directly information provided by the consulate. VFS just compile documents and submit, they are agency not authority.

Leaving that aside, rule of thumb is to just assess your own application. Someone with no previous visa and who is not strongly tied to country he is applying visa from will go through increased scrutiny.

If you are making a sound visa application with rationale behind your visit, dates matching with your flight, you can simply book a hotel you can cancel/refunded. When I was not 100% sure on the date of my arrival, this is how I booked and included in the application. If dates haven't changed, I kept the booking as is.

However in any case, you do need to arrange an accommodation on your name.

Comment: Thanks two accredited agencies said confirmed booking from booking.com is now accepted by the French consulate in London.